# Symfony normalizing array of strings into an Entity

Tags: php, symfony, deserialization

I am receiving a payload that looks like this:

```
{
    "date": "2019-03-14 14:48:26 +0000",
    "events": [
    "E09FDE82-4CAA-4641-87AF-6C092D6E71C1",
    "AE12A6BC-DA37-4C37-BF49-DD0CE096AE00"
    ],
    "location": null
}
```

The wrapper object is an Animal entity and the events is an array of UUIDs that belong to Event entities. These may or may not exist in the events table.

I want to be able to serialize this into an Animal entity using the symfony serializer like so:

```
$serializer = $this->get("serializer");
    if($request->getMethod() == Request::METHOD_POST) {
        $data = $request->getContent();
        $entity = $serializer->deserialize($data, $this->type, 'json');
        ...
        ...
```

What I would like to do is during deserialization, I need to look for that particular key and iterate over it, creating new Events (or getting existing ones) and call the setter on the animal with these.

I have had a look at symfony normalizers but I don't think these are the right things? I made this but not sure where to go from here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Normalizer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

use App\Entity\Event;


class EventNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface {

    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer){
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function normalize($event, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($event, $format, $context);

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $data instanceof Event;
    }
}
```

According to the documentation, this is how you would edit existing values or add new ones but I have no idea how I would tell the normalizer that "hey, when you see this key, you're up, do your thing".

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need a `Denormalizer`, try to implement `DenormalizerInterface`

```
class EventNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface {

   ...

    public function denormalize($data, string $type, string $format = null, array $context = []) 
    {
        // retrieve your events from $data and return the object (Animal) with related events
        // $this->entityManager->find($data['events'][0]) ... 
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, string $type, string $format = null)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply but yeah, I got this working, kind of :D. This is the correct solution but unfortunately it was not for the problem at hand.